# Show Mac OS X system NSMenu instead of default

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenu

I'm wondering if there's a way to get rid of the default NSMenu that you get when you start up a default Mac OS X app, and instead, display the Finders/Systems NSMenu.

(as terrible as it may be, design wise)

Comment: Just remove everything from it. But that is a terrible app design.

Comment: @Joshiah I don't want to just "remove everything from it" I want to display the systems Menu instead.

Comment: @ManOx It's the Finders menu. And you can't display it instead of your own, at least not without giving Finder the focus.

Comment: @ManOx, I see. That makes more sense. Though I still do not know why you would want to do this. But okay. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an application is flagged in its `Info.plist` as background-only (`LSUIElement`), its menu bar will never be displayed on screen, because the application will never be treated as frontmost. This will also cause the application to not be displayed in the Dock, nor in a couple of other standard places (application switcher, Force Quit window, etc). If you decide to go this route, your application should usually provide some sort of alternative UI to show that it's running and to allow the user to quit it (e.g, adding a [NSStatusItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to the menu bar).

That being said, there are a few items which your application's menu bar should always contain, whether it's displayed or not, including:

- Quit, Hide Application / Hide Others / Show All
- Close Window
- Undo, Cut / Copy / Paste, Select All

This is because these menu items have common keyboard shortcuts that users will assume are available at all times (e.g, Cmd+X/C/V for Cut/Copy/Paste).

Comment: To clarify: [LSUIElement (docs)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-108256-TPXREF136) is an Info.plist key. Your app won't show up in the dock or force quit window if used.